# How can I get the x value of kernel density function i.e. kde(x) when kde(x) is max?

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

How can I get the x value of one dimension kernel density estimation function i.e. kde(x) when kde(x) is max ?

I am new to mean shift algorithm. I write a very simple mean shift program base on wiki.
And also this program can generate correct kernel density estimation value by specified x value[below picture].

And what I want to do is to locate the x value when the kernel density estimation function value is max which means to calculate the derivative of kde and make it to zero and then calculate x.

I followed the wiki mean shift introduction to do. But can not get the correct value.
Can anybody tell me how to calculate the x ? Sorry for my poor English.
Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

[kernel density estimation chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2qOr.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*n dimension Guassian function*/
// n is dimension
// h is bandwidth
// x is the Euclidean distance
double gaussian(int n, double h, double x)
{
    const double pi = 3.1415926;
    const double e = 2.718281828;

    double t1 = pow(h, -1.0*n);
    double t2 = pow(2*pi, -0.5*n);
    double t3 = pow(e, -1*((x*x) / (2.0*h*h)) ); 

    return (t1*t2*t3);
}

/*Calc the derivatve of Gaussian function*/
// n is dimension
// h is bandwidth
// x is the Euclidean distance
double deri_gaussian(int n, double h, double x)
{       
    double t1 = gaussian(n, h, x);
    double t2 = -1 * pow(h*h, -1.0);

    return (t1*t2);
}

/*Kernel density estimation function base on Gaussian kernel*/
// n is smp array size
// h is bandwidth
// x is the Euclidean distance
// smp is the double array sample
double gaussian_kde(int n, double h, double x, double smp[])
{
    double sum = 0;
    const int dim = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sum += gaussian(dim, h, (smp[i]-x));
    }

    return sum/n;
}

/*Calc the derivative of KDE and make it to zero to locate the x when KDE is max*/
// n is dimension
// h is bandwidth
// smp is the double array sample
// ssize is the smp array size
double locatex(int n, double h, double smp[], int ssize)
{
    int i;
    double numerator = 0;
    double denominator = 0;

    for (i=0; i<ssize; i++)
    {
        double t = deri_gaussian(n,h,smp[i]);
        numerator += (t * smp[i]);
        denominator += t;
    }

    return numerator/denominator;
}

int main()
{
    double smp[6] = {-2.1,-1.3,-0.4,1.9,5.1,6.2};
    double h = pow(2.25,0.5);
    const int dimension = 1;

    for (double i=-5; i<10; i+=0.1)
    {
        double t = gaussian_kde(6, h, i, smp); //Here can generate correct KDE value like above picture
        printf("KDE:%.6f,X:%.3f\n", t, i); 
    }

    printf("%.8f\n", locatex(1, h, smp, 6) ); //Here can not get the correct value
    return 0;                                 //which means the locatex(1, h, smp, 6) returned value is not the max KDE corresponding x
}
```

Comment: you followed wiki? where?

Comment: [Kernel_density_estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) and [mean shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift)

Comment: mean shift is an iteraive procedure f(x) is not an analytical function where you set its derivateie to zero and find x - try again

Comment: Mr.gpasch Thanks a lot for your advice. Now I've understood the point of mean shift. And finally calculated the correct x value of max kde(x).